# Reading YAML file in Python with accents and special charactets

Tags: python, yaml

I'm trying to read the following YAML file in Python:

```
countries:
  IT:
    "Italia"
  PT:
    "Portugal"
  ES:
    "España"
  PE:
    "Perú"
  FR:
    "France"
  MX:
    "México"
  BR:
    "Brasil"
  CO:
    "Colombia"
  CL:
    "Chile"
  ZA:
    "South Africa"
```

Using this simple code:

```
import yaml
with open('file.yaml') as file:
    countries = yaml.load(file, Loader='yaml.FullLoader')
print(countries)
```

But the result I got is the following:

```
{'countries': {'IT': 'Italia', 'PT': 'Portugal', 'ES': 'EspaÃ±a', 'PE': 'PerÃº', 'FR': 'France', 'MX': 'MÃ©xico', 'BR': 'Brasil', 'CO': 'Colombia', 'CL': 'Chile', 'ZA': 'South Africa'}}
```

As you can see, all accents and special characters like "ñ" are all messed up. Any idea why and how to fix it?

I'm using Python 3.7

Comment: Could not reproduce. Can you try adding `encoding='utf-8'` to the `open` call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read it as UTF-8.

```
with open('file.yaml', 'rt', encoding='utf8') as file:   
     countries = yaml.load(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making your life more complicated than necessary by using
PyYAML. Contrary to the claims that the `FullLoader` ["Loads the full
YAML
language"](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation#how-to-disable-the-warning),
it only parses YAML 1.1 (outdated ten years ago) and doesn't fully
load it.  And you have to take care of too many of the details of non-ASCII
handling.

In ruamel.yaml (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), you can just do

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_file = Path('file.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

countries = yaml.load(yaml_file)
print(countries)
```

which gives:

```
{'countries': {'IT': 'Italia', 'PT': 'Portugal', 'ES': 'España', 'PE': 'Perú', 'FR': 'France', 'MX': 'México', 'BR': 'Brasil', 'CO': 'Colombia', 'CL': 'Chile', 'ZA': 'South Africa'}}
```

So you don't have to open the `Path` instance, nor remember to do that
in a special way. (You can also hand such an instance to `yaml.dump()`)

Answer (score -1):

You can try [gensim.utils.deaccent](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.deaccent)

```
from gensim.utils import deaccent

mydict={'countries': {'ES': 'España', 'PE': 'Perú', 'MX': 'México', 'ZA': 'South Africa'}}

for key, value in mydict.items():
    for k,v in value.items():
        print(deaccent(value[k]))
```

Output:

```
Espana
Peru
Mexico
South Africa
```